# Excel: Multiply arrays based off conditions

Tags: excel

This is giving the run around

[image: Example Below]

Using the picture above as an example, how do I find the cost*days of all approved/unapproved line items?

I played around with a few methods but they all came up short. I think sumproduct is the right path but I cant work additional conditions in the statement.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in wanting to use SUMPRODUCT, you just need to add in a criteria to the function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B7,C2:C7*(A2:A7="Approved"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't really understand the syntax logic there but it definitely worked for me. Thanks a lot, you saved me a big headache!

Comment: No worries. Essentially if the cell has "Approved" in the cell the (A2:A7="Approved") will be value 1, and for any other value 0. This is then added to the SUMPRODUCT function and so in your example when it calculates the row 2 array it will calculate A2*B2*1.